# FFMPEG: Can no longer export >10k pixel video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I used to have FFMPEG perform this command to export valid 10k+ video...

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=10928:768:0:0:violet[outv]" -map "[outv]" output.mp4
```

But I needed upgrade my version of FFMPEG to the latest version to use the `loudnorm` filter. So I upgraded to ffmpeg version 4.1... and the filter became availiable. Suddenly the videos it exports are invalid - OSX will not read them (it did before).

Turning down the width results in a valid video export...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=8196:768:0:0:violet[outv]" -map "[outv]" output.mp4
```

But it certainly doesn't explain why I WAS able to export 10k+ video, but now doesn't?

**Why has upgrading FFMPEG made it less capable?**

After doing some reasearch it seems the upper limit of MP4's is ~8k pixels... if that's the case, how was it even possibly working before?

Comment: Do you have one of the older working files?

Comment: Not with me... just left the office. Can't reproduce a 'working' file right now but ill get one to inspect in around 24 hours. Please come back then!

Comment: Just had a colleague send me an exported video... but now it doesn't open on my machine despite it originally working. I'm not sure what the deal is, but it would appear that we never needed the 10K videos in the first place. I'll have to close this question, its too difficult to replicate the problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I've misread our requirements. We don't use 10K+ videos - we do actually scale them down to fit into 8K which technically solves my problem.